# Installation of Spatialite with Django on windows 10

Tags: django, windows, geodjango, spatialite

I am struggling to find out how to install spatialite for geodjango on windows but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I follow the instructions as per the django page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/ but the tutorial doesn't say what to do after getting the binarys of spatialite
I have tried to put them everywhere but every time I get the same error:

Exception Value:
Unable to load the SpatiaLite library extension as specified in your SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH setting

I tried to put the mod_spatialite.dll file everywhere and try to set  to SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH but it seems I can't get the solution

Any suggestions would be appriciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the binary into Python installation folder eg: C:\Users\huy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39.

Then add `SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = "mod_spatialite"`. This works for me.